# In the nonideal solution, why can't one of the solute be positive deviation and the other be negative deviation?

Tags: solutions

In the nonideal solution, why can't one of the solute be positive deviation and the other be negative deviation?
Let's say A and B makes a nonideal solution.
The moleculat force between A and B means A-B.
Let's say A-A > A-B > B-B.
Then A would evaporate more than in the pure state, and B would evaporate less than in the pure state.
[image]

Comment: Have you read that it's not possible..? Please refer to any text.. it will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

For multiple component systems we use activity coefficient $\gamma$ in modified Roult's law as:
$$K_i=\gamma \frac{P_i^\star}P $$

and $\gamma$ is defined in the terms of $f$ : fugacity or fictitious pressure for a real gas.

You should read further about "Vapour Liquid Equilibrium" for multiple components.

Maybe:  http://www.journalrepository.org/media/journals/BJAST_5/2012/Dec/1355741742-Olaleke312012BJAST1789.pdf. You can see there is no reason why it can't have deviation in multiple directions.

Comment: Please include the essential part of the reference in your answer. Unless the question is a [tag:reference-request], we strongly discourage replies that refer the OP to an external resource, short or long. Helpful links on their own are comments, and links should be archived if possible.